# Event ID 7888 : Transaction Log for database is full

Tags: database, sharepoint, transaction-log

My application is running in the SharePoint Servevr 2007 environment, however I was encounter an error as below:

> "A runtime exception was detected.
>   Details follow.  Message: The
>   transaction log for database 'XX_DB'
>   is full. To find out why space in the
>   log cannot be reused, see the
>   log_reuse_wait_desc column in
>   sys.databases
>
> Techinal Details:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The transaction log for database
>   'XX_DB' is full. To find out why space
>   in the log cannot be reused, see the
>   log_reuse_wait_desc column in
>   sys.databases    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean
>   sendToPipe)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Analytics.Processing.UsageDataProcessor.processSrpUsageData(SharedResourceProvider
>   srp) "

The SQL log was filled up large amount of space within 2 days. 
I've tried to move some of the unused/testing database to another drive to free up some space, but unable to do that because the LDF files was used by another program.

How can the log being fill up so quickly? Please help to fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the database to the simple recovery model to truncate the logs and prevent them from filling up again given adequate backup alternatives.

Read the related question and answers [What's your best practice Recovery Model for SharePoint databases](https://serverfault.com/questions/22138/whats-your-best-practice-recovery-model-for-sharepoint-databases) for more details.

Comment: Also, bulk updates for large transactions should reduce transaction log growth.